# offer for vs. offer to

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which of the two sentences is correct?

1. He refused the organization's offer **for** help.
2. He refused the organization's offer **to** help.

Did a few searches online, and I found that both are widely used.

Answer (score 1):

### Both are OK, although "of" would be better than "for" in example 1.

The confusion arises because the word "help" can be either a noun or a verb.

In the first, "help" is a **noun**. A close paraphrase would be:

> He refused the organisation's offer for assistance.

But the following sounds better and more natural:

> He refused the organisation's offer of assistance/help.

In the second, "help" is a **verb**. A close paraphrase would be:

> He refused the organisation's offer to assist.

Answer (score 1):

Context is important here.

*He refused the organisation’s offer for help.*

The organisation requires his help. They are offering him something in exchange for the help. It is not acceptable. He refused the organisation’s offer for help.

*He refused the organisation’s offer to help*

The organisation wants to help him and he doesn’t want it.

Comment: Since the organizing is offering something, that must be help. Where is there any information that they want something in return?

Comment: @YosefBaskin imagine he’s selling his car. The organisation wants to buy it but made an offer that was not acceptable. He refused the organisation’s offer for the car.

Comment: +1. It’s normally a *request for help* vs an *offer to help*, but you’ve nailed the to/for distinction.

Answer (score -1):

The word “for” is usually used to show:

- Purpose e.i. *“I wear old trousers for painting.”*
- Denote a receiver of something e.i. *“She bought a teapot for her sister.”*
- Express duration e.i. *“I usually go there for a couple of hours.”*
- Indicate exchange e.i. *“The shirt was sold for a dollar.”*
- Replace “because” e.i. *“I missed school yesterday for I was sick.”*

Since Number 1 does not fall under any of these uses, therefore, the correct answer is **Number 2**.

Comment: On what grounds?

Comment: If that is your reasoning, you should include it in your answer. You may want to visit the site's help center to consult the section on proposing good answers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Can you address why the choice you chose as the incorrect choice is incorrect?